# Is coalesced access pattern important for texture and surface memories in CUDA?

Tags: memory, cuda, textures, nvidia

In my experience with CUDA, I mostly preferred the texture memory with CUDA array references because of its 2D/3D spatial caching mechanism and my input data could be arranged as a 2D texture most of the time. Now I have a problem at which I can model the input both as a linear array and a 2D texture. (By the way, when I am talking about texture memory I always mean using it with a 2D CUDA array reference.) I know that the coalesced access pattern is very important when using regular global memory; if the threads in a warp read consecutive addresses with the base address aligned to a 64-byte boundary, then the whole warp can be serviced with a single memory access (coalesced access). I wonder, whether the coalesced access pattern is important for the texture memory, as well. I think it should not be, because the purpose of the texture memory is different; it is optimized for 2D/3D accesses which are close to each other and it updates the texture cache with the desired pixel and a few of the surrounding rows and columns, as far as I know. Therefore I think a consecutive access pattern for a row in the 2D texture memory would not be advantageous, it would probably pollute the texture cache with surrounding row-column data and degrade the performance, in contrast. Anyway, this is only what I am thinking after reading the Programming Guide and other resources and I want to be sure about it: Is coalesced access pattern important for the texture memory as it is in the regular global memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, coalesced access patterns are not important for texture accesses on NVIDIA CUDA GPUs.